# Failure in connecting FTP via FTP clients

Tags: ftp

I set up an FTP server by Serv-U 10.2. It ran normally until recently. Now I cannot connect it by FTP client. Everytime I make a connection, [FTPRush](http://www.wftpserver.com/ftprush.htm) will complain "**Socket operation on nonsocket(10038)**", and [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php) "**Status: Connection attempt failed with '-1'. Error: Could not connect to server**". But if I connect my FTP by browser, like firefox, all goes well. Can anyone give hints on where the problem can be? Thank you~

Comment: Ok, just a punt.  But is there a firewall issue?  Possibly, the browser has a rule while the ftp client has not?

Comment: But I am working under PASV mode.

Comment: Doesn't matter that you are running PASV or not.  If a firewall is going to block it, it will